# WPF : I got problem in draw something on canvas using thread

Tags: wpf, canvas, draw

I try to draw something on canvas every 1 second .Then, I create a thread to call a method to draw after sleep 1 second. The problem is calling Canvas object to draw. The program tell me error message

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Code

```
private void drawTimeTick() {
        ...
        Thread iThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(tickThread));
        iThread.Start();
    }
    private void tickThread(){
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ...
            Canvas.SetLeft(tick, 700);
            Canvas.SetTop(tick, 30);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show("Exception tickThread : "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

How to access Canvas in Thread to draw?

Comment: There are wayyyyy better ways of doing this with WPF than threading; if you must though, use the Dispatcher on the Canvas

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx

Comment: @Pierreten: I think you should post this as an answer, so it can be accepted and voted upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class. It is designed for exactly this scenario, as can be seen in the MSDN examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can call

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                                     {
                                        Canvas.SetLeft(tick, 700);
                                        Canvas.SetTop(tick, 30);
                                     }));
```

(I'm assuming that `this` is some UI control. If not you can use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` instead). It will execute your canvas operations on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I have try DispatcherTimer, It's work.

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += tickThread;
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void tickThread(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            tick.thisTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
            double TickPixel = GetPixel(ClassTimeline.Width, startTime, endTime, tick.thisTime);
            Canvas.SetLeft(tick, TickPixel);
            Canvas.SetTop(tick, 30);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show("Exception tickThread : "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access graphical objects from a different thread from the ones that created it.